# Calculating UMVUE for Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I've started to learn methods of finding UMVUE distribution. I found some nice examples on [this site](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-29.pdf).

I got stuck while evaluating UMVUE for Poisson distribution for a parametric function $g(\theta)$.
[image]

How did the author get
$$\sum_{t=o}^\infty \frac{h(t) n^t}{t!} \theta^t = e^{n \theta}g(\theta)?$$
I thought 
$$\mathbb{E}(h(x)) = g(\theta)$$
should be considered.

Comment: I will just mention that there is [a discussion on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29614/do-we-want-an-umvue-tag) about the newly created (umvue) tag. (It seemed reasonable to let the tag-creator know about this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h(t)n^t}{t!}\theta^t = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h(t)(n\theta)^t}{t!}\text{.}$$
Set $\lambda = n\theta$. Then 
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h(t)(n\theta)^t}{t!} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h(t)\lambda^t}{t!} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h(t)e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda}\lambda^t}{t!} = e^{\lambda}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\left[h(t)\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^t}{t!}\right]\text{.}$$
Since $T \sim P(\lambda)$ (using the notation in your image), then 
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\left[h(t)\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^t}{t!}\right] = \mathbb{E}[h(T)] = g(\theta)$$
due to unbiasedness, hence
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h(t)n^t}{t!}\theta^t = e^{\lambda}g(\theta)=e^{n\theta}g(\theta)\text{.}$$

Comment: Thank you! That's an awesome solution